# Can we use Expressions delimiters "{{ }}" within Statement delimiter "{% %}"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to use "jinja2" for showing comments and reply functionality for my blog website using "Flask" so i was trying to show reply within comments section as show in example or please suggest if anyone have better way to manage comments and its reply with flask:
This is what i mean if comment have reply then its going check in both table comment table & reply table if comment id found in both table if statements print reply data 
{%if {{ comments[0] }} ==reply[0]%}
comments[0] is comment-id(primary key) & reply[0] is reply table comment-id(foreign key)

```
{% for comments in comment_data %} #comments came from different table

<p>User:{{comments[1]}}  </p> #for user email or name
<p>comment: {{comments[2]}}</p> #for comment content
{% for reply in reply_data %} 
    {%if {{comments[0]}} ==reply[0]%} # check comments id from both table

    # i need this portion because every comment can have separate reply 
    section and reply content  

    <p>User:{{reply[1]}}  </p> #for user email or name
    <p>comment: {{reply[2]}}</p> #for reply content

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


{%endfor%}
```

Comment: so what's the problem !!

Comment: its not giving error but i'm not getting proper output... You have any better way to manage that???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer i don't need to use expression delimiters if i want to use jinja2 var in within statement delimiter:
{%if comments[0] ==reply[0]%}